# Radio stops playing when I change volume

Tags: electrical, audio, chrysler

I have bought a 2001 Chrysler Sebring LXi Sedan 4 door car. Recently the radio has started giving problems. Specifically, whenever I change the volume by turning the knob, the radio stops playing... and then all of a sudden after about a minute, starts playing again.

Please anyone who knows what is happenning and how can the problem be fixed?

Comment: [See this meta post](http://meta.mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/1346/85)

Comment: That meta post makes sense - close vote retracted.

Comment: It sounds as though there is a problem with the volume rheostat, but that would be *very* difficult to diagnose without tearing the stereo apart. If it's an electronic problem (no real knob rheostat), sounds like there is a replacement issue ... as in, it's just going to need replaced (ie: no way to cure it).

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar issue with a different car, the issue with mine was a blown capacitor on my headunit, it turned off, and then randomly on. If you're not an electrician / technically minded then easiest route would be to just buy a second hand part and replace it.